# What's does the use of "object={number}" in the following code?

Tags: c++

```
class circle
{
private:
    double a = 0;
public:
    circle(void){}
    circle(double);
};

circle::circle(double a){
    this->a=a;
}

int main(void)
{
    circle c1{ 1 };
    c1 = { 8 };  //what does it mean? Anonymous Object?
    return(0);
}
```

What's the difference between the code "c1={8}" and "c1=circle{8}"? Are they all Anonymous Object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the difference between the code "c1={8}" and "c1=circle{8}"?

They have the same effect here; both construct a temporary `circle` which is move-assigned to `c1` later.

Both perform [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (since C++11), in `c1={8}` the temporary is *copy-list-initialized*, in `c1=circle{8}` the temporary is *direct-list-initialized*, both call `circle::circle(double)` at last.